# OpenMP Fortran Particle Method Speed Decrease

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

In trying to optimise some code I find that using [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) linearly increases the time it takes to run. The representative section of code that I am trying to speed up is as follow:

```
    CALL system_clock(count_rate=cr)
    CALL system_clock(count_max=cm)
    rate = REAL(cr)
    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(c1)

    DO k=1,ntotal
      CALL OMP_INIT_LOCK(locks(k)) 
    END DO  

    !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(i,j,k)
    DO k=1,niac
      i = pair_i(k)
      j = pair_j(k)
      dvx(:,k) = vx(:,i)-vx(:,j)
      CALL omp_set_lock(locks(i))
      CALL DGER(dim,dim,-1.d0, (disp_nmh(:,j)-disp_nmh(:,i)),1, &
        (dwdx_nor(dim+1:2*dim,k)*V_0(j)),1,  particle_data(i)%def_grad,dim)
      CALL DGER(dim,dim,-1.d0, (-dvx(:,k)),1, &
        (dwdx_nor(dim+1:2*dim,k)*V_0(j)) ,1,  particle_data(i)%vel_grad(1:dim,1:dim),dim)
      CALL omp_unset_lock(locks(i))
      CALL omp_set_lock(locks(j))
      CALL DGER(dim,dim,-1.d0, (dvx(:,k)),1, &
          (dwdx_nor(3*dim+1:4*dim,k)*V_0(i)) ,1,  particle_data(j)%vel_grad(1:dim,1:dim),dim)
      CALL DGER(dim,dim,-1.d0, (disp_nmh(:,i)-disp_nmh(:,j)),1, &
        (dwdx_nor(3*dim+1:4*dim,k)*V_0(i)),1,  particle_data(j)%def_grad,dim)    
      CALL omp_unset_lock(locks(j))      
    END DO  
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO 

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(c2)
    t_el = t_el + (c2-c1)/rate
    WRITE(*,*) "Wall time elapsed: ", t_el
```

Note that for the simulation I am testing k=14000 which I thought was a reasonable candidate for running in parallel. So far as I know I have to use the locks to ensure that threads which are given the same value of "i" (but a different value of "j") cannot access the same index of the arrays which are being written to at the same time. I cannot figure out if the version of [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) (`sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev`) which I use is thread safe. I ran a simulation with 8 cores and got the same result as without OpenMP so I am guessing that it could be. BLAS is used, in this case, to calculate and sum the outer product of many 3x3 matrices.

Is the implementation of OpenMP above the best way to speed up this code? I know very little about OpenMP but my guesses are that:

- the memory being all over the place ("i" is sequential but "j" is not)
- the overhead in starting and closing down all the threads
- the constant locking and unlocking
- and maybe the small loop size (although I thought 14000 would be sufficient)

are significantly outweighing the performance benefits. Is this correct? Or can the code above be modified to get some performance gain?

**EDIT**

I should probably add that the code above is part of a time integration loop. Hopefully this explains why the elapsed time is summed.

Comment: I do not know your entire problem, and what each part of it does. This makes it very hard to comment on it. Judging from the little I see you are locking everything except for the creation of i and j and dvx. How much time goes into that compared to the DGER calls? Since i and j are computed at runtime, my guess is, the compiler has a hard time figuring out what you are doing with it anyway effectively hindering optimization (which I assume would decrease performance, but increase scalability :P). If it is at all possible, do some profiling to see how much time goes into which part of your cod

Comment: Once you have done that, you know which parts are worth parallelizing. Otherwise your assumptions seem pretty solid ... again, hard to without the complete example. If you want good advice on how to optimize your code, I suggest you stick to that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In addition to the [mcve], please also provide a clear description of the performance you observed, including how you measured, as well as your system specifications.

Comment: Using BLAS for 3x3 sounds wrong to me. I would definitely write that using loops and `matmul()`.

Comment: From looking at the code it seems that you're essentially doing a reduction  operation and are using the locks to ensure that only one thread updates the result at a time. As all of the work appears to be inside locks this means the loop will be essentially executed essentially serially, but with the added overhead of acquiring and releasing locks. It looks like `k` is a flattened index for all the pairwise `i-j` interactions? If so you may find using a twice nested loop over `i` and `j` may give you more flexibility.

Comment: If i is sequential then it is easy to rejig this so you don't need the locks there - parallelise over the i values and within each i treat all the js that interact with the given j. Then as d_1999 says j would be better done by a reduction.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments. I'll try to edit my question to include a full MCVe but that might take some time (and thought) considering that this is a piece of a solver. I naively thought the code included would be enough.